# WdfWaitLockCreate function retrun STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES after windows 10 1903 update

Tags: windows, visual-c++, kernel, wdk, kmdf

The problem occurred in windows file system kernel driver that running in windows 10 1903.
When the driver trying to create lock using the `WdfWaitLockCreate(WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &CA_agentFileObjectLock);` 
i am receiving NTSTATUS `STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`
in previews version of windows 10 (all of them) the NTSTATUS i am getting back from the function is `STATUS_SUCCESS`.

i didnt find any record from windows docs that somethings has change with this specific function.
NTSTATUS documention information is: "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the API."

Comment: Which WDK are you using?

Comment: WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 10.0.18362.1

Comment: the different is only in Windows Version or WDK Versions?

Comment: this happen only with windows 1903 update. this problem caused a blue screen to our system because the allocation is never working. this is the original problem that occurred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448489/windows-update-1903-causing-file-system-driver-to-crash